# Stored procedure does not return records

Tags: mysql, asp.net, stored-procedures

I am using my first stored procedure in mySQL as follows :

```
CREATE DEFINER=`pubuducg`@`%` PROCEDURE `IsUserExists`(IN LoginEmail varchar(100))
BEGIN
    SELECT LOGIN_USER_ID AS USERS 
    FROM login 
    WHERE LOGIN_EMAIL = @LoginEmail;
END
```

I am calling the procedure in C# ASP.net as follows :

```
if (oMySQLConnecion.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
{
    MySqlCommand oCommand = new MySqlCommand("IsUserExists", oMySQLConnecion);
    oCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LoginEmail", UserEmail.EmailAddress);

    var sqlResult = oCommand.ExecuteReader();

    userExists = (sqlResult.HasRows ? true : false);
    oMySQLConnecion.Close();
}
```

If I execute the SQL statement manually:

```
SELECT LOGIN_USER_ID AS USERS 
FROM login 
WHERE LOGIN_EMAIL = @LoginEmail;
```

it works fine.

My table collation is set to "utf8 - default collation".

Column (LOGIN_USER_ID) collation set to 'Table default'.

I called stored procedure in mySQL Workbench as follows :

```
CALL IsUserExists('abcdefg@gmail.com');
```

Always no records exist in `oCommand.ExecuteReader()` object.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. IT is related to '@' sign in stored procedure.
Right way to use it :

```
        CREATE DEFINER=`pubuducg`@`%` PROCEDURE `IsUserExists`(IN LoginEmail varchar(100))
BEGIN
SELECT LOGIN_USER_ID AS USERS FROM login WHERE LOGIN_EMAIL = LoginEmail;
END
```

No need to put '@' sign inside sql query.